# Flutter: Unable to generate build files, A Required package was not found

Tags: android, linux, flutter, dart, cmake

Tried to build a basic linux app following the official Flutter [google-colab](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) tutorial and got stuck with this error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)


Exception: Unable to generate build files`
```

OS: Linux Mint
IDE: VScode

Tried to find the missing modules so i could install. Was unsuccessful. Need more expertise in that part. Please help :)

edit: installed libgtk-3-dev since it was a requirement as stated from `flutter doctor`
which said

```
root@lax:/home/lax/Flutter/vibeo# flutter doctor
   Woah! You appear to be trying to run flutter as root.
   We strongly recommend running the flutter tool without superuser privileges.
  /

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Linux Mint 21.1 5.15.0-57-generic, locale en_IN)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    ✗ GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
      They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install libgtk-3-dev)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

and still the build fails

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
ERROR: Flutter failed to create a directory at "/home/lax/Flutter/vibeo/.dart_tool/flutter_build/a631d39312be8637492918f28fa31d2e".
Exception: Build process failed
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: add the output of `flutter doctor`

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the post. Quite new to flutter and realized I had few requirements pending but still the build failed.

Comment: you need to install `libgtk-3-dev`, I think it's in the repo of linux Mint

Comment: absolutely. I did install it. But still the build fails.
`Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
ERROR: Flutter failed to create a directory at "/home/lax/Flutter/vibeo/.dart_tool/flutter_build/a631d39312be8637492918f28fa31d2e".
Exception: Build process failed
Exited (sigterm)`

I think i need to modify a few permissions for flutter to access it

Comment: and there is not missing linux packages in flutter doctor anymore, right?

Comment: try `flutter clean` and run again

Comment: Nope. Just a chrome executable is missing. Not related I believe
`[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Linux Mint 21.1 5.15.0-57-generic, locale en_IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability`

Comment: Oh wow~ It worked! thanks a lot Hydra!